# Java Swing - How to create custom components with auto size adjustment to the parent

Tags: java, resize, components, shapes

I'm trying to build a custom triangle component that has the same features as a JComponent (like a JButton per say).

The porpoise of the program will be to add triangle on a mouse click exactly where the mouse is and to handle a mouseover event by highlighting the bg of the shape.

I let the default layouts(or null), because while using others, the applications just doesn't place the triangles where I want...

Right now my major issue is how to adjust the size of the triangles with direct proportionality relative to the form size? So that if I reduce the frame size 50% all the components are down that value as well.

One other issue is that the JComponent requires a rectangular area to handle events, for what I've seen there's no way countering this, so if I try to click on the affected area it will just ignore it instead of creating a new triangle there.

And yet another problem is that sometimes while moving out of the triangle from the bottom it is still green.

Thanks!

Here is the SSCCE:

```
// TriangleCustom.java
package TriangleCustom;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.geom.GeneralPath;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class TriangleCustom {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Triangle");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setSize(1200, 800);
        Panel p = new Panel();
        f.add(p);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

}

class Panel extends JPanel {
    // the offsets are the area (rect border) to contain the triangle shape
    private final int xOFFSET = 25;
    private final int yOFFSET = 50;

    ArrayList<TriangleShape> triangleAL = new ArrayList<TriangleShape>();

    public Panel() {
        setBounds(0, 0, 800, 400);
        // setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black,2));
        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                addTriangle(new Point(e.getX(), e.getY()), new Point(e.getX()
                        - xOFFSET, e.getY() + yOFFSET), new Point(e.getX()
                                + xOFFSET, e.getY() + yOFFSET));
            }

        });
    }

    private void addTriangle(Point topCorner, Point leftCorner,
            Point rightCorner) {
        final TriangleDTO tdto = new TriangleDTO(new Point(25, 0), new Point(0,
                50), new Point(50, 50));
        TriangleShape ts = new TriangleShape(tdto);
        ts.setBorderColor(Color.BLACK);
        ts.setFillColor(Color.RED);
        ts.setBounds((int) (topCorner.getX() - 25), (int) topCorner.getY(), 51,
                51);
        triangleAL.add(ts);
        this.add(ts);
        repaint();

    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.draw(new Rectangle2D.Double(0, 0, 799, 399));
    }
}

// the custom component in a shape of a triangle
class TriangleShape extends JComponent {

    private GeneralPath triangle = new GeneralPath();
    private TriangleDTO tdto = new TriangleDTO();
    private Color borderColor = new Color(0);
    private Color fillColor = new Color(0);

    // Constructor
    public TriangleShape(TriangleDTO tdto) {
        this.tdto = tdto;
        triangle.moveTo(tdto.getTopCorner().getX(), tdto.getTopCorner().getY());
        triangle.lineTo(tdto.getLeftCorner().getX(), tdto.getLeftCorner()
                .getY());
        triangle.lineTo(tdto.getRightCorner().getX(), tdto.getRightCorner()
                .getY());
        triangle.closePath();

        addMouseMotionListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
                // there are some issues when going out of the triangle from
                // bottom
                if (triangle.contains((Point2D) e.getPoint())) {
                    setFillColor(Color.GREEN);
                    repaint();
                } else {
                    setFillColor(Color.RED);
                    repaint();
                }
            }
        });

    }

    public void setBorderColor(Color borderColor) {
        this.borderColor = borderColor;
    }

    public void setFillColor(Color fillColor) {
        this.fillColor = fillColor;
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setPaint(fillColor);
        g2d.fill(triangle);
        g2d.setPaint(borderColor);
        g2d.draw(triangle);
    }

}

// just a plain DTO for the triangle points
class TriangleDTO {

    private Point topCorner = new Point();
    private Point leftCorner = new Point();
    private Point rightCorner = new Point();

    // Constructors
    public TriangleDTO() {
    }

    public TriangleDTO(Point topCorner, Point leftCorner, Point rightCorner) {
        super();
        this.topCorner = topCorner;
        this.leftCorner = leftCorner;
        this.rightCorner = rightCorner;
    }

    // Getters and Setters
    public Point getTopCorner() {
        return topCorner;
    }

    public void setTopCorner(Point topCorner) {
        this.topCorner = topCorner;
    }

    public Point getLeftCorner() {
        return leftCorner;
    }

    public void setLeftCorner(Point leftCorner) {
        this.leftCorner = leftCorner;
    }

    public Point getRightCorner() {
        return rightCorner;
    }

    public void setRightCorner(Point rightCorner) {
        this.rightCorner = rightCorner;
    }

}
```

Comment: 1. Please call super.paintComponent, otherwise you run into repaint issues. 2. Take a look at the [Shape](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Shape.html) API and [Working with Geometry](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/geometry/index.html) for ideas on detecting non-rectangular points. 3. You will need to know the "original" size of the container that the shape was added to and will need to compare that with the size of the component when it's resized, best use a [custom layout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/LayoutManager.html)

Comment: 4. You want to use the mouseEntered and mouseExited events from the MouseListenet instead of mouseMoved

Comment: 5. IMHO A dedicated triangle component is overkill

Comment: For hit detection override `JComponent.contains()`. See [TriangleButton](http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=119370) for example.

Comment: thanks @MadProgrammer this is educational stuff I won't be using triangles but other irregular shape that needs interaction with mouseEvents. Why to call super.paintComponent isn't that implicit already? I used the MouseMoved because of the rectangular sensory area that every jcomponent has, I supposed it was not possible to customize this. I guess I will need to learn how to deal with custom layouts, a good exercise :)

Comment: Super is only implied on default constructors, all other methods you get to choose if you want to invoke the super, which you really, really should do with paint methods. If you use the Shape API, you can use mouse enter/move/exit and do hit detection via the shape, this will allow you to use irregular shapes with the panels